# Compare columns in two tables and create a SQL view

Tags: sql

I have two tables and the data is stored as shown in both tables

**TabelA**:

```
cert_id  custid
-----------------
  002    C1
  003    C1
  004    C1
  005    C1
  006    C1
  007    C2
  008    C2
  009    C2
  010    C2
```

**TableB**:

```
cert_id                 custid
-------------------------------
002, 003, 004           C1
008, 010                C2
```

I am trying to create a where it looks for same data in TableB (`cert_id`) and if it matches in the column, it should not be in the view.

From the example above whatever `cert_id` is in the column it should compare in the other table then list the ones that are not in TableB

So the new view should be showing something like this:

**View1**:

```
cert_ids
--------
005
006
007
009
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.cert_id from tablea a inner join tableb b 
on b.cert_id not like'%'+ a.cert_id  +'%' 
and a.custid=b.custid
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2c90dc/1

Comment: Note that this is non-standard SQL. In SQL the concatenation operator is `||` not `+`